# Glassfish 4.1 Bug : session.invalidate nullpointer exception

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

I updated Netbeans from 7.3 to 8.01 and Glassfish from 4.0 to 4.1 .Now i have this exception in my project.Why?Session isn't null but i have a nullpointerexception.
Where am I doing wrong?
Thanks

```
12|public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
13|
14|@Override
15|protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
16|        throws ServletException,IOException{
17|    
18|    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
19|    if(session!=null)
20|        session.invalidate();
21|    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
22| }//doGet
23|
24|}//LogoutServlet
```

Error code:

```
Session event listener threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener.getSessionContext(WeldTerminalListener.java:65)
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener.sessionDestroyed(WeldTerminalListener.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:910)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:854)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:842)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.invalidate(StandardSession.java:1603)
at  org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.invalidate(StandardSessionFacade.java:204)
at store.web.LogoutServlet.doGet(LogoutServlet.java:20)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: This is a bug of Glassfish
.
https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21166

Comment: Also, on line 19, `session` will never be null.  Use `request.getSession(false)` if you want null instead of a new session.

Comment: From JavaEE Api: getSession() "Returns the current session associated with this request, or if the request does not have a session, creates one. ".The line 19 is unnecessary.So this is a bug in Glassfish 4.1

Answer (score 2):

The same problem on Netbeans 8.1 and Glassfish Open Source Edition 4.1 (build 13). You have to disable CDI by creating or modifying `beans.xml` file at `./WEB-INF` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="none">
</beans>
```

`bean-discovery-mode` is set to `none`.

More info [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/default_cdi_enablement_in_java).

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are not leveraging bean injection into you application, creating a ***beans.xml*** file (without the need to declare any bean inside) with below content under *"src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/"* have resolved the issue for me once:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Comment: The file beans.xml already exists.Netbeans created it for me.Thanks anyway.